# How does Philips Hue bridge work?

Tags: web-services, http, web, iot, philips-hue

I was wondering recently on how the philips hue bridge work in case the device to control is on a different Network (over the internet remote control).

Is there an intermediate server in place to do the job of taking commands and the bridge polls the server to get the devices working ?

Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an intermediate server at Philips that receives the requests from the Hue app and sends them to the bridge. This is why signing in to your meethue account is required (so that it can link to the right bridge).

How it's made ? No idea, I do not think it's explained somewhere for now.

Comment: Okay.. Implies that the bridge continuously polls the server (http) to see a list of issued commands and then triggers the device ?

Comment: Don't know how that is implemented but maybe there is some websocket or something equivalent for notifications.